# Evento que realiza uma consulta ao banco de dados quando clicarmos em um <tr> de uma tabela

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Olá. 
Estou fazendo um sistema que ao formulário ser submitado, é gerado uma tabela com os dados da pesquisa. Até ai tudo bem. Agora eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para quando eu clicar em um botão (), que está dentro de um  da tabela,  seja disparado um evento que faça uma consulta via ajax no banco de dados, e retorne um json com o resultado da consulta e preencha uma div. Lembrando que pegaremos o value desse  para usarmos como filtro no select que será feito no arquivo PHP.

```js
//CÓDIGO PARA PREENCHIMENTO DA LISTA COM OS DADOS DA PESQUISA 
 
 $('#formulario-consulta').submit(function(e)
 {   
  e.preventDefault();
  var formulario = $(this);
  var retorno = inserirFormulario(formulario);
 
 });

 function inserirFormulario(dados)
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
   //dataType: "json",
   type:"POST",
   data:dados.serialize(),
   url:"interface-resultado-pesquisa.php",
   async:false
   
  }).done(function(data)
  {
   
   var atividades = "";
   
   $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor)
   {      
    atividades += '<tr value="'+ valor.codigo +'">';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.COD + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.EMPRESAS + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.TIPO_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.STATUS + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_VENCIMENTO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_INICIO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_FIM + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.codigo + '</td>';
    //atividades += '<td><button class="btn-warning" value="'+ valor.codigo +'">Detalhes</button></td>';
    atividades += '<td><button class="btn-warning" id="'+ valor.codigo +'">Detalhes</button></td>';
    atividades += '</tr>';
   });
   
   $('#registros-atividades').html(atividades);
   
   
  }).fail(function()
  {
   
   
  }).always(function()
  {
   
   
  });
  
 }

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //




/* FUNÇÃO PARA PREENCHER A <DIV ID="espaco-detalhes" */

$('div#espaco-detalhes tr td button').click(function(e)
{   
 e.preventDefault();
 
 var botao = $(this).attr('id');
 var retorno = pesquisarDetalhes(botao);
  
});

function pesquisarDetalhes(dados)
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
   dataType: "html",
   type:"POST",
   data:"botao=" + dados,
   url:"interface-consulta-comentarios.php",
   async:false
   
  }).done(function(data)
  {
   
   var detalhes = "";
   
   $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor)
   {
    detalhes += "<p>" + valor.DETALHES + "</p>";
    
   });
   
   $('#espaco-detalhes').html(detalhes);
   
   
  }).fail(function()
  {
   
   
  }).always(function()
  {
   
   
  });
  
 }
```

```html
<?php
 
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 
 require_once("conexao-com-banco.php");

?>


<?php
    // Determinar localidade BR
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
  
 //INICIANDO A SEÇÃO DO USUÁRIO CONECTADO
 session_start();
 
 if ( !isset($_SESSION["user_portal"]) )
 {
  header("location:index.php"); // SE NÃO ESTIVER CONECTADO, RETORNA PARA A PÁGINA DE LOGIN
 }
 else
 { 
  // SE HOUVER ÊXITO NA CONEXÃO, REALIZAR UMA MENSAGEM DE BOAS DINDAS.
  
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $hora = date("H");
  if($hora > 06 AND $hora < 12)
  {
   $mensagem_boasvindas = "Bom Dia, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . " !";
  }
  else if($hora >= 12 AND $hora < 18)
  {
   $mensagem_boasvindas = "Boa Tarde, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . " !";
  }
  else
  {
   $mensagem_boasvindas = "Boa Noite, " . $_SESSION["nome"] . " !";
  }
  
 }
   
 $user = $_SESSION["nome"];
?>


<?php
 //Consultas ao banco de dados
 require_once("interface-consulta-banco.php"); // CHAMANDO ARQUIVO DE CONSULTA AO BANCO PARA PREENCHER OS CAMPOS "AUTOMATICAMENTE DO FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA COM INFORMAÇÕES DO USUÁRIO

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Sistema - JCA</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      
  <link href="_css/estilo-telainterface.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DESTA PÁGINA -->
  <link href="_bootstrap4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->
  

      
  
</head>


<body>  
  
    
  <div class="container-fluid">
   
   <header>
   
    <h1>SISTEMA WEB</h1>
    <p><i>"Uma mente que se abre a uma nova idéia jamais voltará ao seu tamanho original"</i></p>
   </header>
   
   
   <!-- DIV COM MENSAGEM DE BOAS VINDAS AO USUÁRIO -->
   
   <div id="mensagem">
    <h5><?php echo $mensagem_boasvindas ?></h5>
   </div>
   
   
   
   <div class="row">
    
    <!-- INÍCIO DA DIV COM O FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="pesquisa">
    
     <form id="formulario-consulta"> <!-- FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->
      <div class="form-inline">   
      
        <div class="row">
        
         <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="botao-resumo" style="margin-top: 0">Resumo por Status</button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar:</h5>
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosTodos" value="Todos" class="form-control" checked> Todos: 
            </label>
           </div>
           
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosComum" value="Comum" class="form-control"> Comum: 
            </label>
           </div>
           
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosExtra" value="Extra" class="form-control"> Extra: 
            </label>
           </div>
           
           <div class="radio">
            <label>
             <input type="radio" name="optionRadios"id="optionRadiosUrgente" value="Urgente" class="form-control"> Urgente: 
            </label>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar por data de:</h5>
           <div class="radio">
            <select name="data" id="data" class="input-sm form-control">
             <option  value="Inicio">Início </option>
             <option  value="Finalizacao">Finalização </option>
             <option  value="Vencimento" selected>Vencimento </option>
            </select>
           </div>
                                  
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
           <h5>Filtrar por período:</h5>
           De: <input type="date" name="dataInicial" id="dataInicial" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:40%;">
           Até: <input type="date" name="dataFinal" id="dataFinal" class="input-sm form-control" style="width:40%;">
                                        
          </div> 
         </div>
        </div>

       
       <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          
         <div class="">
         
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>COD</h5>
            <select  name="cod" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
            <?php
             while($linha_cod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_cod))
             {
            ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?>
             </option>

            <?php
             }
            ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div> 
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Empresa</h5>
            <select name="empresas" id="empresas" class="input-sm form-control" style="width: 100%">
            <option></option>
             <?php
             while($linha_empresas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_empresas))
             {
             ?> 
              <option value="<?php echo $linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"]; ?> "> 
               <?php echo $linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"]; ?>
              </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div> 
           
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Tributação</h5>
            <select name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
            <?php
             while($linha_tributacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_tributacao))
             {
            ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"]; ?>
             </option>

            <?php
             }
            ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Atividade</h5>
            <select name="atividade" id="atividade" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
             <?php
              while($linha_atividade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_atividade))
              {
             ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"];?>"> 
              <?php echo $linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"]; ?>
             </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
           <div class="radio">
            <h5>Status</h5>
            <select name="status" id="status" class="input-sm form-control">
            <option></option>
             <?php
              while($linha_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_status))
              {
             ?> 
             <option value="<?php echo $linha_status["STATUS"]; ?> "> 
              <?php echo $linha_status["STATUS"]; ?>
             </option>

             <?php
              }
             ?>
            </select>
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-1 form-group">
           <h5>Pesquisar</h5>
           <input name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Enviar">
           
          </div>
                    
         </div>
        </div>              
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div> 
    
   </div>   
      

      
   <div class="row">
    
    <!-- DIV QUE EXIBE O RESULTADO DA PESQUISA DO FORMULÁRIO -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="resultado-pesquisa">
          
     
     <!-- DIV QUE EXIBE AS INFORMAÇÕES DE RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
     
     <div class="col-lg-12" id="exibicao">
      
      <!-- TABELA QUE EXIBE DINAMICAMENTE COM O PHP OS RESULTADOS DA CONSULTA AO BANCO -->
      
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="resultado-exibicao">
       
       <thead>
        <tr><th>COD</th><th>EMPRESA</th><th>TRIBUTAÇÃO</th><th>TIPO DE ATIVIDADE</th><th>STATUS</th><th>DT.VENC</th><th>DT.INÍCIO</th><th>DT.FIM</th><th>Código</th><th>Comentários</th></tr>
       </thead>
       
       <tbody id="registros-atividades">
        
        
        
       </tbody>
       
       
      
      </table>
            
      
     </div>
     
     
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
   <!-- DIV PARA EXIBIÇÃO DO RETORNO DA CONSULTA DOS CAMPOS DETALHES E FEEDBACK -->
   
   <div class="row" id="detalhesfeedback">
    
    <!--DIV QUE EXIBE O CAMPO DETALHES COM O RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 panel panel-primary" id="detalhes">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">DETALHES</h4>
     </div>
       
       
     <div class="panel-body" id="espaco-detalhes">
      <p> 
     
      
      </p>
     </div>
           
    </div>
    

    <!--DIV QUE EXIBE O CAMPO FEEDBACK COM O RETORNO DA CONSULTA -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-5 panel panel-primary" id="feedback">
     
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">FEEDBACK DA GERÊNCIA / RESPONSÁVEL SETOR</h4>
     </div>
       
       
     <div class="panel-body" id="espaco-feedback">
      
      <p>
      
      </p>
      
     </div>
           
    </div>
    
    <!-- DIV COM OS BOTÕES QUE EXECUTAM AÇÕES NO BANCO -->
    
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="botoes-detalhes-feedback">
        
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-inserir-detalhes">Inserir Detalhes</a></button>
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-success"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-reabrir-atividades">Reabrir Atividades</a></button>
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-reabrir-atividades">Sem Movimento/Arquivo</a></button>
     
    </div>
    
    
    <!--DIV MODAL QUE ABRE QUANDO CLICAMOS NO BOTÃO INSERIR DETALHES -->
    <!--
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="modal-inserir-detalhes">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close"
          aria-label="close"
          data-dismiss="modal">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Insira um Comentário</h4>
       </div>
       
       <div class="modal-body">
        
        <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-inserir-destalhes">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comentario">Comentário</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="comentario-inserir-detalhes" id="comentario-inserir-detalhes" style="resize: none"></textarea>
         </div> 

         <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="enviar-detalhes" id="enviar-detalhes">
         
        </form>

         
       </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    -->
    
    
   </div>
   
   
   
  </div>
  
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  
  
  <script src="_jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
  <script src="_bootstrap4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="_scripts/interface-script.js"></script>
  
  
  
  
 
  
</body> <!-- FIM DO BODY -->
</html> <!-- FIM DO HTML -->

<?php
 // Fechando Conexão
 
 mysqli_close($conecta);
 
 
?>


<!-- ARQUIVO PHP PARA FAZER A CONSULTA COM O BANCO DE DADOS interface-consulta-comentarios.php -->

<?php
  // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO
  require_once("conexao-com-banco.php"); 
  
  //CONSULTA NO BANCO QUE PREENCHE A ÁREA DE DETALHE NA PARTE DE BAIXO DA TELA INTERFACE.PHP
  
   session_start();
  
   $usuario = $_SESSION["nome"];
   
   $detalhes = $_POST['botao'];
     
   $mostrarDetalhes = "SELECT DETALHE FROM tbl_atividades WHERE RESPONSAVEL = '$usuario' AND codigo = '$detalhes'";
   
   $resultado_select = mysqli_query($conecta, $mostrarDetalhes) or die("ERRO na conexão com banco de dados");
      
   $return = array();
   
   while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado_select))
   {
    $return[] = $linha;
   }  
   

   //echo json_encode($return)
   echo json_encode($return);
    
  
  
  
?>
```

Vou mostrar a imagem a princípio pra ver se vocês me dão alguma ideia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em um daqueles  que lista informações da atividade, seria feita uma consulta e preenchidos as  DETALHES e FEEDBACK DA GERÊNCIA.

(OBS: Eu já fiz um código ajax para fazer isso, só que não está dando certo. Acho que pelo motivo dos  serem preenchidos dinamicamente na tabela)

Obrigado!

Comment: Você precisa inserir a tabela html, o ajax e o php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eu já fiz um código ajax para fazer isso, só que não está dando certo.
>   Acho que pelo motivo dos serem preenchidos dinamicamente na tabela

**Esse é um dos problemas.**

1) Esse evento está errado: `$('div#espaco-detalhes tr td button').click(function(e)..` pois não há uma lista neste local. O correto é `$('#registros-atividades tr td button').click(function(e)..`

2) Após a alteração anteriro, é necessário inserir o evento após a criação da lista, pois antes de você inserir a tabela com a lista que foi criada no php usando o ajax, esta lista, não existia, portanto o código não tem referências desta nova lista no DOM. Então, o click, simplesmente não funciona. E como o click não funciona, o ajax não é acionado.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor)
{                       
    atividades += '<tr value="'+ valor.codigo +'">';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.COD + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.EMPRESAS + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.TRIBUTACAO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.TIPO_ATIVIDADE + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.STATUS + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_VENCIMENTO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_INICIO + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.DT_FIM + '</td>';
    atividades += '<td>' + valor.codigo + '</td>';
    //atividades += '<td><button class="btn-warning" value="'+ valor.codigo +'">Detalhes</button></td>';
    atividades += '<td><button class="btn-warning" id="'+ valor.codigo +'">Detalhes</button></td>';
    atividades += '</tr>';
});

$('#registros-atividades').html(atividades); // insere a lista
// INSERE O EVENTO DE "CLICK" APÓS A ALTERAÇÃO NO HTML
$('#registros-atividades tr td button').click(function(e)
{           
    e.preventDefault();

    var botao = $(this).attr('id');
    var retorno = pesquisarDetalhes(botao);

});
```